# Codeigniter Deletes are not allowed unless they contain a "where" or "like" clause

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the next query and return this

```
function delete_dispatchByIdPlataforma($idPlataforma)
{       
    $this->db->delete("delete from dispatch where id_licencia in
    (select id_licencia from licencias where id_plataforma = $idPlataforma)");      
}
```

so I tried this:

```
$this->db->select('id_licencia');
        $this->db->from('licencias');
        $this->db->where('id_plataforma', $idPlataforma);
        $where_clause = $this->db->get_compiled_select();

        #Create main query
        $this->db->where("`id_licencia` IN ($where_clause)", NULL, FALSE);
        $this->db->delete('dispatch');
```

But now doesn't return anything and the query doesn't execute.

Comment: At the end i did a select whit joins and get only the id in an array, Then with this array of id i did a delete with active record like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
// First get the id to delete of my table    
function getIdDispatchToDelete($idPlataforma)
    {
        $this->db->select('ID_dispatch');
        $this->db->from('dispatch');
        $this->db->join('licencias', 'licencias.id_licencia = dispatch.id_licencia');
        $this->db->where('licencias.id_plataforma', $idPlataforma);     
        $query = $this->db->get();
        //echo $this->db->last_query();die();

        if($query){
            if($query->num_rows>0){             
                foreach ($query->result() as $fila){
                    $data[] = $fila->ID_dispatch;           
                }   
                return $data;           
            }
        }else 
            log_message('error', 'No se han encontrado Dispatch a borrar'.$this->db->_error_message().' - '.$this->db->last_query());
    }

// Seccond i did the delete whit the id got it.
     function delete_dispatchByIdPlataforma($idPlataforma)
    {       
        $idDispatch = $this->getIdDispatchToDelete($idPlataforma);
        $this->db->where_in('id_dispatch', $idDispatch);
        $this->db->delete('dispatch');
    }
```

Comment: You can accept your own answer by clicking on the green tick.